# tree visualization with many root nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, visualization

I am new to making javascript tree visualizations,can anyone give some examples on creating visualization with many root nodes. I am trying to make the following

[image]

Comment: Add a top-level placeholder element as your root node?

Comment: could please elaborate with small specific example